# Why content gets populated as a sibling of router outlet in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, router

In *ngRoute*/*ui.router*, content gets loaded inside *ng-view*/*ui-view*, but in angular 2 it gets loaded as a **sibling** of router *outlet*. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router uses `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` to add components dynamically and that is the way `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` works.

This discussion might reveal some more in-depth insight https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9035#issuecomment-223983064

Comment: Thanks, this thread also asks exactly the same question:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8529

Comment: Yup, it's a common question